# SQL SELECT from XML field as multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

I am working on a SELECT query from a table ORDERS, which contains an XML field. Among other data that XML field contains order line items. I know this isn't best design but I have to stick to it.
I need to select all order line items.

This gets me the first line items for each order:

```
SELECT
OrderNumber,
[OrderItems].value('(/items/item/sku/node())[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS SKU
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate = '2016-04-09'
```

Is there a way to get all line items for all invoices?

Comment: Although I think that @har07 has got the right idea I'd advise you to always include same sample data and expected output. Without the actual XML any answer is reading in the magic bulb...

Comment: @Shnugo, thank you, I'll do that from now on. And yes, har07's answer was correct, it  worked as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`nodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) with `APPLY` to shred XML data into multiple records. For example, assuming that you want to shred the XML at `<sku>` element level, you can do as follow :

```
SELECT
    OrderNumber,
    SkuColumn.value('.', 'varchar(20)') AS SKU
FROM Orders
    CROSS APPLY OrderItems.nodes('/items/item/sku') SkuTable(SkuColumn)
WHERE OrderDate = '2016-04-09'
```

Comment: Worked as a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please help me modify the above query to be able to also get the ProductName along with the SKU from the same table? I am really struggling with the syntax here.

Comment: Never mind, I got it. Thanks again for your help!

SELECT
    OrderNumber,
    ItemColumn.value('SKU[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS SKU,
    ItemColumn.value('ProductName[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS ProductName
FROM Orders
    CROSS APPLY OrderItems.nodes('/items/item') ItemTable(ItemColumn)
WHERE OrderDate = '2016-04-09'